# Change values from categorical to nominal in R

Tags: r, categorical-data

I want to change all the values in categorical columns by rank. Rank can be decided using the index of the sorted unique elements in the column.

For instance,

```
> data[1:5,1] 
[1] "B2" "C4" "C5" "C1" "B5"
```

then I want these entries in the column replacing categorical values

```
> data[1:5,1]  
[1] "1" "4" "5" "3" "2"
```

Another column:

```
> data[1:5,3]
[1] "Verified"        "Source Verified" "Not Verified"    "Source Verified" "Source Verified"
```

Then the updated column:

```
> data[1:5,3]
[1] "3" "2" "1" "2" "2"
```

I used this code for this task but it is taking a lot of time.

```
for(i in 1:ncol(data)){
  if(is.character(data[,i])){
    temp <- sort(unique(data[,i]))
    for(j in 1:nrow(data)){
      for(k in 1:length(temp)){
        if(data[j,i] == temp[k]){
          data[j,i] <- k}
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Please suggest me the efficient way to do this, if possible.
Thanks.

Comment: Take a look at `plyr`s `mapvalues`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here a solution in `base` R. I create a helper function that convert each column to a factor using its unique sorted values as levels. This is similar to what you did except I use `as.integer` to get the ranking values.

```
rank_fac <- function(col1) 
   as.integer(factor(col1,levels = unique(col1)))
```

Some data example:

```
dx <- data.frame(
  col1= c("B2" ,"C4" ,"C5", "C1", "B5"),
  col2=c("Verified"    ,    "Source Verified", "Not Verified"  ,  "Source Verified", "Source Verified")
)
```

Applying it without using a for loop. Better to use `lapply` here to avoid side-effect.

```
data.frame(lapply(dx,rank_fac)
```

Results:

```
#       col1 col2
# [1,]    1    3
# [2,]    4    2
# [3,]    5    1
# [4,]    3    2
# [5,]    2    2
```

#### using data.table syntax-sugar

```
library(data.table)
setDT(dx)[,lapply(.SD,rank_fac)]
#    col1 col2
# 1:    1    3
# 2:    4    2
# 3:    5    1
# 4:    3    2
# 5:    2    2
```

### simpler solution:

Using only `as.integer` :

```
setDT(dx)[,lapply(.SD,as.integer)]
```

Comment: Neat, but I reckon `data.frame(lapply(dx,rank_fac)` or `replace(dx, , lapply(dx, rank_fac))` or even `sapply(dx, rank_fac)` is better than `do.call(cbind..`

Answer (score 0):

Using `match`:

```
# df is your data.frame    
df[] <- lapply(df, function(x) match(x, sort(unique(x))))
```