# R - Change column variable from categorical value to nominal

Tags: r, dataset

I have a CSV dataset where a column X has values between [1-4] which I would like to replace for ["Low","Medium Low","Medium High","High"] according to its value. So now dataset$X would be a vector of those categories instead of a vector of numbers.

I've checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42938647/change-values-from-categorical-to-nominal-in-r) example, but it seems like a complicated version of what I'm trying to fix (it seems since it's from fixed values to fixed categories, there should be an easier and cleaner way). Any suggestion on how to do it?

PS: In the first place I tried it with "levels" and "cut" but since it is one fixed number and not a range it wouldn't work properly.

Comment: Very nice! To change the dataset had to add "df$X <-" to what you said, but worked perfectly, thanks a ton :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `X` to subset your categorical vector.

```
dataset$X <- c("Low","Medium Low","Medium High","High")[dataset$X]
dataset
#            X
#1         Low
#2  Medium Low
#3 Medium High
#4        High
```

Data:

```
dataset <- data.frame(X=1:4)
```